# Java Move to next and previous records

Tags: java, jdbc

With the code below i can move to the last record of the database and to the first record of the database. I create the next() method for move to the next record. It move from the first record to the second record but it show a this error(SQLException Result set after last row. I can't continue with my project until i can move records next and previous. Any help pleas

```
public void CreateResultSet(){
    try{
        stmt = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "select * from OAUTOPARTS_PRODUCT";
        stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}

 public void first(){
    CreateResultSet();
   try{
            rs.first();
            String add1 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_ID");
            txtPartNumber.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_NAME");
            txtPartName.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getNString("COST");
            txtPrice.setText(add3);

   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}

 public void next(){
     CreateResultSet();
     try{                                 
        while(rs.next()){
             rs.next();
             String add1 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_ID");
            txtPartNumber.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_NAME");
            txtPartName.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getNString("COST");
            txtPrice.setText(add3);
         }
     }catch(Exception e){

         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
     }


 }

  public void last(){
    CreateResultSet();
   try{
        rs.last();
            String add1 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_ID");
            txtPartNumber.setText(add1);
            String add2 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_NAME");
            txtPartName.setText(add2);
            String add3 = rs.getNString("COST");
            txtPrice.setText(add3);

   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    txtPartNumber = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtPartName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtPrice = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnFirst = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnLast = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnNext = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    btnFirst.setText("First");
    btnFirst.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnFirstActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnLast.setText("Last");
    btnLast.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnLastActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnNext.setText("Next");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnNextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(144, 144, 144)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(btnFirst, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(txtPartNumber, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtPartName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtPrice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 152, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(btnNext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(btnLast, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(89, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(78, 78, 78)
            .addComponent(txtPartNumber, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(txtPartName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(txtPrice, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 53, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnFirst, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnLast, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addComponent(btnNext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 44, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnLastActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    last();
}                                       

private void btnFirstActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    first();
}                                        

private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    next();
}
```

Comment: Beware this pattern: `while(rs.next()) { rs.next(); /* ... */ }` you're advancing 2 rows.

Comment: So Arthur what is the correct code for this? I new to this and i could not continue working with this until i solve this issue. I searched over the internet and i cannot find any solution. that why i post this problem here to see if anyone can help.

Comment: `while (rs.next())` and that's it. Remove the second call. `rs.next()` already makes the cursor move to the next row.

Comment: I removed the rs.next() call and it only move to the last record. I know this is a loop and it will move to the last record. So how i do that the record move to the next record and not to the last record. thanks

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `next` button should advance to the next row. If this is the case, replace `while (rs.next())` with `if (rs.next())`.

Comment: I did that already and it do nothing. As you can see in the code the rs.first and the rs.last are working perfect but the rs.next and rs.previous are not. Im very frustrating no to have a solution for this. If you have any suggestion just let me know. thanks

Comment: If you `CreateResultSet()` each time you push `next`, you won't be able to move past the first row of your result set. By the way, this will lead to a major leak of your database connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void updateForm() {
    String add1 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_ID");
    txtPartNumber.setText(add1);
    String add2 = rs.getNString("PRODUCT_NAME");
    txtPartName.setText(add2);
    String add3 = rs.getNString("COST");
    txtPrice.setText(add3);
}

public void first() {
    try {
        if (rs.first()) {
            updateForm();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

public void next() {
    try {
        if (rs.next()) {
            updateForm();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}

public void last() {
    try {
        if (rs.last()) {
            updateForm();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

And move `CreateResultSet()` in the constructor of your class, so that is gets only created once.

I've factored out the form update in a private method, that gets called in your `first`, `next` and `last` method.

I have this: Here where the CreateResultSet() should be go?

```
public MainForm() {
    initComponents();
    connect = DbConnection.dbConnection();
    CreateResultSet();


}

public void CreateResultSet(){
    try{

        stmt = connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "select * from OAUTOPARTS_PRODUCT";
        stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    }catch(Exception e){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. Where exactly i move the CreateResultSet()? in the InitComponets()

Comment: `initComponents()` is generated by Netbeans, so you shouldn't mess with it. Instead, `initComponents()` must be called somewhere, probably in the constructor of your class. Move `CreateResultSet()` just before or just after the call to `initComponents()`.

Comment: Thank you Arthur with your suggestion i could solve my problem now i can continue with my project.

Comment: Then at least mark the provided solution as useful.